# Issues using pubnub access manager to publish with php

Tags: php, pubnub

I am trying to use pubnub with their access manager to authorize certain users to a specific channel and then publish a message to the channel after the user has been granted read/write rights.  I must be doing something wrong with the publish() call on this after granting access to the user.  The first part of code below returns what looks like a successful response for the grant() but the publish() call results in :

Fatal error: Call to undefined method access::publish() in /home/dayfv98/public_html/mobile/pubtest.php on line 48

Here is my code:

```
<?php


error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);


require('pubnub.php');

require('pam.php');


$chat_entry =  addslashes(trim($_POST['chat_entry']));


// CONNECT TO ACCESS MANAGER

$manager = new access(
    "MY_PUB_KEY...not included for security",
    "MY_SUB_KEY...not included for security",
    "MY_SEC_KEY...not included for security"

);


## Grant User Access
print_r($manager->grant(
    "chat",        // CHANNEL
    "44444",  // STRING (AUTH KEY)
    true,                // READ
    true,                // WRITE
    0                    // TTL in MINUTES
));


$manager->publish(array(
    'channel' => 'chat', ## REQUIRED Channel to Send
    'message' => $chat_entry

));



?>
```

Answer (score 2):

The access manager library is not intended to be used to do anything outside of the scope of the access manager. It is only intended for grants, revokes, and audits.

You will need to use the normal PubNub sdk, but when constructing your PubNub object, provide the auth token you have previously granted.

**EDIT : ** The PHP SDK seems to have some issue with Access Manager right now. I've done some minor hotfix modifications to address this and have included them into a gist, but please keep an eye on the official repository on github for a newer version : https://gist.github.com/keyosk/9c86b981948a3cf7f378

For instance, to use the auth token you granted in your example above, you would do this :

```
$pubnub = new Pubnub(array(
    'publish_key' => 'MY_PUB_KEY',
    'subscribe_key' => 'MY_SUB_KEY',
    'auth_token' => '44444',
));

$pubnub->publish(array(
    'channel' => 'chat',
    'message' => $chat_entry
));
```

Comment: Thanks guys..will use your hotfix for now..assuming this is a temporary replacement for pubnub.php right?

Comment: @jacksprater That's right. For the time being you can use this to replace the existing pubnub.php - please keep an eye on the official repository for a new version.